# How to aggregate all data in SQL for a specific column? Or how to avoid '...not contained in either an aggregate function'

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregation

A quick question: how can I avoid the error

> not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause

I want to have id's grouped for every single country. Is it possible?

```
SELECT  country_code AS 'Country', UserInfo.Id       
FROM [ip2location].[dbo].[ip2location_db1] as IpRange with(nolock)
JOIN [dbo].[USERINFO] as UserInfo
    ON (SELECT dbo.IPAddressToInteger (UserInfo.LastIp)) BETWEEN IpRange.ip_from AND IpRange.ip_to
WHERE 
    UserInfo.RoomId = 84 AND 
    country_code != 'UA' AND 
    country_code != 'BY' AND 
    country_code != 'KZ' AND 
    country_code != 'RU' 
GROUP BY country_code
```

Comment: I think I've got the answer to my own question: just don't use GROUP BY at all :)

Comment: When you use GROUP BY, SQL server uses the aggregation to return one value per value present in your GROUP BY statement. That means that if you want to retrieve more information than the grouping field and the aggregation, you should either add the fields to the group by clause or consider some other option (like a window function (e.g. PARTITION BY COUNTRY_CODE))

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is the field *UserInfo.Id*, in the [SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) clause.  Because it is not part of the [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) SQL Server doesn't know what to do with it.

When using GROUP BY any field that does not appear in the grouping must be aggregated, using one of the [aggregate functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx).

Consider this example table:

```
Country Sales
UK      10.10
UK      20.10
USA     15.25
```

Grouping by country would return:

```
Country
UK
USA
```

Adding sales to the SELECT causes a problem.  There are three sales values and only two rows.  SQL Server needs instruction on how to turn the three source rows into 2 output rows.  You could [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187810.aspx) the sales.  That would return:

```
Count   Sales
UK      30.20
USA     15.25
```

Or you could always add Sales to the group by.  That would return the original three rows.

As a rule of thumb, when using GROUP BY any field not included in the grouping must be wrapped in a aggregate function (SUM, MIN, MAX, etc).